# How to pass the downloaded image using piccaso from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android

I am using cardlayout in my project and I am retrieving all data from Firebase. I used three classes.
In the MainActivity I am getting the image using piccaso.
**MainActivity.java**

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img);
ContactInfo obj=new ContactInfo();
obj.image=img;
```

**ContactInfo.java**

```
public ImageView image;
```

**CardLayout.java**

```
ContactInfo object=new ContactInfo();
Cardlayout.img=object.image.
```

My problem is I want to pass the image from MainActivity to CardLayout. By doing like this my app getting crash.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958442/passing-image-fetched-from-a-remote-source-in-an-activity-to-another-activity-us) answer. You can do the same.

Comment: what is coming in the logcat?

Comment: Are you getting *TransactionTooLongException*?

Comment: After following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958442/passing-image-fetched-from-a-remote-source-in-an-activity-to-another-activity-us) am getting  a log like  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just load an image in one activity and then pass URL to the second one. Since Picasso caches all the image second call with the same URL will result in fetching the same image from the cache:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView)
```

To check if the image was loaded from the cache just enable indicators:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true).
```

Red - it was fetched from network
Blue - from the disk cache
Green - from the memory cache

UPD:

If you are have a separate class that calls Picasso.with(MainActivity.this) just do something like this:

```
public class Util {
   private Context context;

   public Util(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }

   public void callPicasso() {
       Picasso.with(context)......
   }
}
```

And in MainActivity:
    public void onCreate() {

```
    Util u = new Util(this.getApplicationContext());
    u.callPicasso()
```

Or just use you picasso calls directly in the MainActivity

Comment: Yes, you were right i done like this  Picasso.with(this).load(ci.uri_feed).fit().centerCrop().into(contactViewHolder.feedimg);    But i am getting error saying     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: In what class are you calling this part: Picasso.with(MainActivity.this) ? If that is a different class than MainActivity you should pass a context to that class and use it instead of MainActivity.this

Comment: @koldan if you dont mine can you please tell me how to pass the context.please.